# Не работают кнопки в плеере при использовании React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

использую сторонний скрипт для того, чтобы нарисовать плеер у себя на странице.

Автор скрипта предлагает вставлять HTML на страничку так:

```
<div id="yohoho" data-title="Тайна Коко"></div>
<script src="//yohoho.cc/yo.js"></script>
```

Что делаю я?

```
export const Kino = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = React.useState(undefined);
  
    return (
        <div>
            <div id="batya">
            </div>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search"
                value={title}
                onChange={(e)=>setTitle(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={()=>{
                const el= document.querySelector("#yohoho")
                const batya=document.querySelector("#batya")
                el?.remove()
                const newY=document.createElement('div')
                newY.id="yohoho"
                newY.dataset.title=title
                newY.dataset.player="collaps,kodik,hdvb,bazon,ustore,alloha,pleer,videospider,videocdn,trailer"
                newY.dataset.separator=","
                batya?.appendChild(newY)

                Start()
            }}>Search</button>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Функция Start() вызывает инициализирующую функцию в скрипте yo.js

В чем суть проблемы? Плеер появляется, однако при нажатии на кнопки переключения плееров ничего не происходит. При этом, если вставить код (предложенный разработчиком) просто в HTML разметку все прекрасно работает и кнопки нажимаются. Подозреваю, что проблема именно в React и он почему то не хочет регистрировать онклики на кнопки.
На скриншоте нужные кнопки справа.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю неправильно и почему плееры не меняются?

Answer (score 0):

Показали бы page с демонстрацией.
Попробуйте обернуть этот div еще одним так `<div><div id="batya"></div></div>`